# How do I have multiple datasources with the same JNDI name in JBoss?

Tags: java, database, jboss, jndi

So, I have a situation where I will be deploying multiple ear files, each of which I need to configure with a different database (potentially).

Right now I have a *-ds.xml file that is deployed in JBoss, with a JNDI name that all my portlets and servlets use to look up the database connection. If I deploy more than one ear file with a *-ds.xml file that points to a different database, but with the same JNDI name, the deployment barfs. Shouldn't JNDI be more modular to prevent naming collision when deploying different application to isolate them.

It will take quite some time to change my lookup in the code, so is there a way to deploy that will work? The only other idea I had would be to set a JNDI property as the value for the datasource name to look up, and then look up that JNDI property first and retrieve the datasource based on the retrieved "key." This seems kind of hackish to me...

Comment: Arent you missusing JNDI in this case? JNDI simply maps a datasource to a identifier on application server level. This way your deployment is separated from the datasource on which it works. Different datasources should get different JNDI identifiers though since they are actually, well guess it, different datasources. Think of it as a simple `Map<String,DataSource>`. JNDI is defined in a server scope and not in a deployment scope.

Comment: Re "what's the point of JNDI", what's the point of using something under a grand assumption that you haven't verified and then blaming the tool? In this case you have just assumed that each .ear has its own namespace. Do you have any basis for that assumption?

Comment: It seemed a logical thought that each ear deployed on a web server would have its own namespace; IE: that you could deploy multiple different ear files each referencing the same JNDI name, each with different database values. For example, I am working with other developers, and if I need to make sweeping database changes, I don't want to have to change the database lookup name for everyone when I could leave that the same.

Comment: If it is different environments, it is best to use multiple instances of application server (dev, testing, prod).

Comment: @Shinzul It may 'seem a logical thought' to you, but it is still an unverified assumption on your part, and querying the usefulness of something just because it doesn't conform to your preconceptions is certainly not a logical thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the different data source defined on the application server with different name (on the server namespace) and then map it to a resource-ref name (this time component namespace, so each application can have its own one) via the deployment xml file.

For JBoss prior as7: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowDoICreateAResourceRef for as7: https://community.jboss.org/message/629666

Comment: This seems very similar to what I described above - 'set a JNDI property as the value for the datasource name to look up, and then look up that JNDI property first and retrieve the datasource based on the retrieved "key."' Am I correct in making that association?

Comment: No, JNDI look up will return directly the data source.  Using the as7 naming convention: you define the data source under the java:/jboss name space which cover the entire application server.  In the application you can bind this jboss name to a java:comp/env name.  In your application all look up will be done via the java:comp (or java:app if you define it on the ear level) name space which is limited to the war/ear.  So you have a java:comp/env (or java:app/env) name which will be a synonym of a java:jboss one.  The java:jboss name will need to be different for each data source.